# template specialization in classes with new template

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, template-specialization

I have code similar to this:

```
class test {
template <typename T>
 void func(T rhs);

template <typename V>
void func(std::vector<V> rhs);
};
```

I can I do this? This seems to be a specialization, but I have to introduce a new template. Also gcc tells me an error like that, when I try to do it like this:

```
template<>
template<V>
void func(std::vector<V> rhs);

explicit specialization in non-namespace scope
too many template-parameter-lists
```

Comment: You're **not** specializing `V` in your code sample. Should be `int`, `double` or `MyClass`, shouldn't it?

Comment: I try to have the function for general types and for a vector, but also with general types. When I try to to this, the compiler takes the most general function, so the one with T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specialize, just inline it:

```
class test {
    template <typename T>
    void func(T rhs)
    {
    // Your plain T code goes here
    }

    template <typename V>
    void func(std::vector<V> rhs)
    {
    // Your vector specialized code goes here (no extra specialization needed)
    }
};
```

Or if you prefer to separate the definitions out to a `.tcc` file do:

**test.h:**

```
class test {
public:
    template <typename T>
    void func(T rhs);

    template <typename V>
    void func(std::vector<V> rhs);
};

#include "test.tcc"
```

**test.tcc:**

```
template <typename T>
void test::func(T rhs)
{
    std::cout << "Your plain T code goes here" << std::endl;
}

template <typename V>
void test::func(std::vector<V> rhs)
{
    std::cout << "Your vector specialized code goes here" << std::endl;
}
```

Fully working sample at [ideone](http://ideone.com/N93Jbv).

Comment: No, since then I have a class for every type I feed in, but I only want the function to have the template. So I want a function for lets say int, double etc and a function for vectors to these types.

Comment: @user2988020 OK, got it. But then you don't want _specialization_ I'd say.

Comment: That works. I had a cast operator going wrong, so the compiler always picked the wrong function. But templates must be defined in the header file, mustn't they?

Comment: @user2988020 _templates must be defined in the header file_ They are effectively, look at the `#include "test.tcc"`. This is just to avoid littering the class interface declaration with it's implementation.